# Django: Get all instances connected to some set of instances

Tags: python, django

I have 2 models:

```
class Listing:
    title = models.CharField()

class Location(models.Model):
    listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing)
```

Given a set of locations, `l = Location.objects.all()`

I want to find `l.listing` (Which is not the correct command)

Something like `listings = Listing.objects.filter(listing_set_in=l)`.

It has to be **as efficient as possible**.

Comment: is `l` *always* the list of *all* `location`s?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem not always, sometimes its a set of multiple filtered locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to find all items from Listing, that present in `l` queryset. To do so, you can filter Listing queryset by values from `l`.
You can use Django subquery to reduce amount of queries.

w/ Subquery

```
Listing.objects.filter(pk__in=l.values('listing_id'))
```

The same with Subquery

```
from django.db.models import Subquery
Listing.objects.filter(pk__in=Subquery(l.values('listing_id')))
```

Comment: @Anrey Rusanov , sorry but this isn't what I need. `l` contains a set of locations, `Listing.objects.filter(pk__in=l)` will return nothing. I need to get a list of listings contained within `l`